# JQuery on click Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, parseint

I'm trying to get the progress bar animation to run when I click the `.trigger`. I'm getting the `data-percentage` value in the logs but the animation isn't running. It works without using `$(this).closest()` but I cannot figure out why the animation isn't running with my current JS code.

```js
$(".list").on("click", ".trigger", function() {
  var e = $(this).closest(".item");
  $(".progressbar").attr("data-percentage", e.find("#percent").text());
  var t = e.find("#percent").text();
  return (
    $(".progressbar").each(function() {
      var n = e,
        r = t;
      console.log(t),
        parseInt(n.data("percentage"), 10) < 2 && (r = 2),
        n.children(".bar").animate({
          width: r + "%"
        }, 500);
    }), !1
  );
});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.trigger {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progressbar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.bar.money-green {
  background: #3cd3ad;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fcb31c;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="trigger">
      <p id="percent">22</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progressbar" data-percentage="">
  <div class="money-green bar"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the code for you. Clean and clear way

You don't need to return in `onclick` function. And you should use `$(this)` inside `.each` to get current index element

```
$(".list").on("click", ".trigger", function() {
  var e = $(this).closest(".item");
  var t = e.find("#percent").text();
  $(".progressbar").attr("data-percentage", t);

  $(".progressbar").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".bar").animate({
      width: t + "%"
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

See the [codepen](https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/BrPPOv?editors=1010)